# Why does Spring's MessageDigestPasswordEncoder take `{}` into the salt? The example in its javadoc does not seem to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm upgrading from Spring Security 4.x to 5.x.

The `ReflectionSaltSource` from Spring 4 lets us configure a custom salt. But that's removed in Spring Security 5. I then found out that I should use  `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`. It has a long detailed java-doc but unfortunately the doc is a bag of words without conveying any structured information (I tried  multiple times; my bad if I was ignorant).

Anyways I thought I should do the following based on my limited understanding.

*Old system with 4.x* - `myEncodedPassword` and `mySalt` are passed separately to the encoder.

*New System with 5.x* - Pass one field with the value `{mySalt}myEncodedPassword` to the `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`

However, that did not work. **The Problem** was that when `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` sees `{mySalt}encodedPassword`, it uses `{mySalt}` (with the {}) as the salt instead of using `mySalt` as the salt . I'm confused.

Here's a coding example. I used Groovy to reduce noise.

```
@Grab(group='org.springframework.security', module='spring-security-core', version='5.1.4.RELEASE')
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder

String password = 'myPassword'
String salt_1 = 'mySalt'
String salt_2 = '{mySalt}'
// http://www.lorem-ipsum.co.uk/hasher.php generated below hashes
String encodedPasswordWithSalt_1 = '57bc828628811a10496215e217b7ae9b714c859fc7a8b1c678c9a0cc40aac422'
String encodedPasswordWithSalt_2 = 'a18b53fc58843def1e08e00a718f40d6f8eda0b97ef97824b5078c1fad93c0c5'

MessageDigestPasswordEncoder encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('SHA-256')
println "expected=true, actual=" + encoder.matches(password, "{${salt_1}}${encodedPasswordWithSalt_1}") // <--- expected to match but did not
println "expected=false, actual=" + encoder.matches(password, "{${salt_1}}${encodedPasswordWithSalt_2}") // <--- why does this match?
```

The output is

```
expected=true, actual=false
expected=false, actual=true
```

I'm hoping to find a way to support SHA256 with custom and separate salt for each user password.

---

If anyone's interested, I created a ticket on GitHub - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6594 . No solution so far. I will update here if there's any. So this is still an unanswered question.

Comment: Asked on github (@phani I saw it's you created, wrote for other answeres) : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6594

Comment: Yep, thanks for commenting. I thought there might be more attention there.

Comment: You can create your own password encoder that implements the org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder interface.
We did that in our project. Or your can fix extractSalt method in MessageDigestPasswordEncoder and push it in to the spring-security project :)

Comment: @AnatolySamoylenko yep. thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the issue is in the `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` class

By debugging it in the method `private String extractSalt(String prefixEncodedPassword)` they try to extract salt by returning `prefixEncodedPassword.substring(start, end + 1);` where `start` is the index of the prefix `{` while end is the index of suffix `}` and it stops to the first suffix it matches so what happens in your code?

It happens this:

```
MessageDigestPasswordEncoder encoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder('SHA-256')
println "expected=true, actual=" + encoder.matches(password, "{${salt_1}}${encodedPasswordWithSalt_1}") //It's not matched because the extracted salt will be {mySalt} and not mySalt
println "expected=false, actual=" + encoder.matches(password, "{${salt_1}}${encodedPasswordWithSalt_2}") //It's matched because the extracted salt will be {mySalt} and not mySalt
```

I state I don't know if it's a bug or not, in any case in your scenario it should be enough to properly investigate and properly modify the method

```
private String extractSalt(String prefixEncodedPassword) {
        int start = prefixEncodedPassword.indexOf(PREFIX);
        if (start != 0) {
            return "";
        }
        int end = prefixEncodedPassword.indexOf(SUFFIX, start);
        if (end < 0) {
            return "";
        }
        return prefixEncodedPassword.substring(start, end + 1);
    }
```

This method is inside the `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` class

I hope it's useful

Angelo

Comment: Thanks for clarification.I feel silly that I had refused to believe it was a bug. As I'm new to `spring-security` and the related topics, I thought I was doing something wrong.